# ModuleNotFoundError but only when mocked

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a package called `my_package` with a single module called `my_module`:

```
$ tree my_package/
my_package/
├── __init__.py
├── my_module.py
├── my_module.py~
└── __pycache__
    ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    └── my_module.cpython-36.pyc
```

`my_module` has a function called `compute_something`:

```
$ cat my_package/my_module.py
def compute_something():
    return 0
```

I'm trying to mock that function for unit testing purposes:

```
$ cat mocks.py
import mock

from my_package import my_module

def unmocked():
    print(my_module.compute_something())

@mock.patch('my_module.compute_something')
def mocked(mock_compute_something):
    mock_compute_something.return_value = 1
    print(my_module.compute_something())

unmocked()
mocked()
$ python mocks.py
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mocks.py", line 14, in <module>
    mocked()
  File "/home/pcoccoli/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1345, in patched
    keywargs) as (newargs, newkeywargs):
  File "/home/pcoccoli/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/pcoccoli/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1325, in decoration_helper
    arg = exit_stack.enter_context(patching)
  File "/home/pcoccoli/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 330, in enter_context
    result = _cm_type.__enter__(cm)
  File "/home/pcoccoli/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1398, in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
  File "/home/pcoccoli/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1573, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/home/pcoccoli/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1245, in _importer
    thing = __import__(import_path)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'
```

As you can see, `my_module` exists and is found just fine (I call it form the `unmocked` function, and you can see its output), unless I try to `mock.patch` it.  I don't understand why this is so.

Comment: I guess no one wants to be mocked.

Comment: My guess would be that the decorators calls that function from a different file where my_module isn't recognized. What happens when you place the import statement inside of the mocked function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The decorator doesn't call the function - it should patch it in the current namespace.

Comment: ```python
@mock.patch('my_module.compute_something') 
```
here the path method from the mock class is called in another session with a string reference to my_module.compute_something. This other session has no idea what or where this is.

Comment: could you try to to change 
`from my_package import my_module`
to 
`import my_package `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch I see that it should be:

```
@mock.patch('mocks.my_module.compute_something')
```

This is because I have imported `my_module` into `mocks.py`.  My code in the question is missing the leading "mocks." in the `target`.

Comment: Is it Bad Form to answer your own question?